# Customized keyboard - Putting numbers on top of characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uikeyboard

I want to draw a customized keyboard with numbers on top of characters. It should look something like the attached screenshot. Any idea how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: I have tried using all the default options given by iOD SDK - UIKeyboardTypeDefault, UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable, UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation, UIKeyboardTypeURL, UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad, UIKeyboardTypePhonePad, UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad, UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress, UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad, UIKeyboardTypeTwitter. But none helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the inputAcessoryView property of the UITextField to add a view with the numbers above the default keyboard, you have to draw the number keys:

**@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputAccessoryView**

The default value of this property is nil. Assigning a view to this property causes that view to be displayed above the standard system keyboard (or above the custom input view if one is provided) when the text view becomes the first responder. For example, you could use this property to attach a custom toolbar to the keyboard.